# スイッチングハブのトラブル

Tags: network

ご教授お願いします。会社で下記のようなネットワークを組んでいます（SH: switching hub）。5年間ほど同じ構成で稼働しており、構成に変化はありません。端末は増えている可能性があります。

```
光フレッツ
|
ルーター（RTX1210）
|(A)             　　　　|(B)
SH              　　　　 SH
|<約10分岐>      　　　　 |<8分岐>
端末(約20台)やSHや無線機  端末(約20台)やSHや無線機
```

(A)には何も問題は起きていませんが、(B)が突然8分岐のうち2分岐しかつながらないようになり、1日後には8分岐すべてつながらなくなりました。SHを交換しましたが、やはり2-3分岐しか繋がりません。8分岐のうち、どこでもいいので2-3分岐を抜くと、他のすべてがつながるようになります。どこを抜けばどこがつながるのか、規則性は見い出せません。特定の分岐のみがつながらないわけではありません。

ハードウェアの問題ではないような気がしており、どこを直せばいいのか皆目見当がつきません。お気づきの点がありましたら教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 事象は「(B)配下の端末 - インターネット が疎通しない」のか「(B)のSH配下の端末間が疎通しない」のか(あるいはそれ以外の事象)質問に追記した方が良いかと思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。(B)配下のインターネットも繋がりませんし、(A)(B)配下にあるネットワークプリンタやNASにも繋がりません。リンクランプはどれも点灯しています。

Comment: ハード側要因ならどこかに loop があるとか (だとするとわずかでも動くことが解せぬが) ケーブルの接触不良や断線しかかりがあるとか。ソフト側原因なら dhcp で配っているローカル IP アドレス数が max に来てるとか固定 IP 設定なマシンがいて dhcp とけんかしてるとか NAT セッション数が max に来てるとか。こういうトラブルは現地で実際触れる人でないとどうにもできないです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。IPが足りていることは確認しました。その他の点に関して、確認していきたいと思います。

Comment: 繋がる繋がらないではなく、IPが取れたか取れてないか、その後はパケットキャプチャして何が出来て何が出来ていないのか調べるか、できないならスイッチを取り替えて調べるしかないような気がします。現象の報告が大雑把すぎる気もしますが。
まあこのサイトであれこれ聞くような話ではなく、リモートならチャットや通話などでリアルタイムに調べるような話かと思います。

Comment: 774RRさん、dameoさん：ご指摘ありがとうございます。下記にも記載しましたが、(B)配下にあった無線機（家庭用）を外すと、すべての通信が正常化することがわかりました。なぜこの無線機が原因なのかは、私にはわかりません。いまご報告してもしかたないかもしれませんが、ご指摘の項目を分かる範囲で調べました。NATセッション数はピーク時で5%程度でした。つながらないときは、IPはとれますが、通信ができない状態でした。このたびは大変勉強になりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

次の点を考慮すると、(B)配下のSHのMACアドレステーブルが溢れている可能性が考えられます。

- ルータ外だけでなく、ルータ内の通信ができない。
- (A)配下の端末の通信はできている。
- SH等のリンクランプは正常。
- (B)配下のSHを交換しても事象が解消しない。
- 端末が増えている可能性がある。

(B)配下の端末数を調査して、想定以上に存在しているのであれば、セグメント分割をする(=間にL3SW等を挟む)ことで解消するかも知れません。

Comment: user20098さん：ご回答ありがとうございます。  その後調査を続けた結果、(B)配下にあった無線機（家庭用）を外すと、すべての通信が正常化することがわかりました。なぜこの無線機が原因なのかは、私にはわかりません。  なお、ご指摘のMACアドレステーブルをルーターから調べてみましたが、最大43と大丈夫そうでした。  このたびのご指摘は私の知らないことも多く、大変勉強になりました。ありがとうございました。